# How can I get the result modulo INT_MAX?

Tags: java, string

If I try to apply: `Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE) + "9");`
I get a `NumberFormatException`.

But I need to get the remainder modulo `Integer.MAX_VALUE` from the `String` representation.

How can I achieve that?

UPD: `Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE) + "9");`   is just an example. The string can potentially have the value even more than max of Long.

Comment: The answer is `9`. You're multiplying the original number by `10`, adding `9` and then taking this value modulo your original number.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Could you look at the updated question?

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Phylogenesis I have a String field which held a string value consistng of an arbitrary number of digits. I need to get the Integer value modulo INT_MAX.

Comment: Then use the `BigInteger` class. That is there for arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic.

Comment: You could parse it yourself to avoid both overflow and arbitrary precision, but that's probably more effort than it's worth. Unless we're talking several KB of numbers here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). This allows math using very large numbers.

The following will allow you to do modulo with very large numbers:

```
BigInteger number = new BigInteger(myValueAsString);
BigInteger intMax = BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
BigInteger remainder = number.remainder(intMax);
```

Comment: Why `BigDecimal` over `BigInteger`?

Comment: @Phylogenesis Good point, will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

To hold large number of input you can try BigInteger class. create one object that will hold your String input and modulo it with second BigInteger class object that will hold MAX_VALUE of integer.

You can write code as :

```
        BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(str);
        bigInteger  = bigInteger.remainder(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE)));
        System.out.println(bigInteger);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
int i = (int)Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE) + "9");
```

note: I would use (Integer.MAX_VALUE + "9")

Comment: The issue is the String can potentially causes overflow even long. I just provide `String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE) + "9"` as an example of Exception.

Comment: try my example, there is no exception

Answer (score 1):

you could also try it like this:

```
    System.out.println(Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE + "9")) % 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(str);
```

try the following code

```
int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE ;
System.out.println(i+1);
```